# ProgressDialog communicate with AsyncTask in android

Tags: android

Tips or ideas on how ProgressDialog can communicate with asyncTask.
For example when I click the button, the program will validate the input to internet, This is should not be interupted. so I use ProgressDialog.

After progressDialog.dismiss(), I need to refresh the view by calling the asyncTask.
I have tried some ways but it's failed, for example 
* I execute asynTask after progressdialog.dismiss().
* put execution asynctask inside dialogbox after progressdialog thread.

in other word, is there any way to tell asynctask that progressdialog has been dismissed. Or is there communication such as message between threads ?

here is the example of my code:

```
    btnPost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stockProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PostActivity.this, 
                    "Please wait...", "Check the post");
            new Thread() {
            public void run() {
            try{
                /* Connect to Internet API */
                    stockProgressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) { }
            // Dismiss the Dialog
            }
            }.start();
            new LookUpTask().execute();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to tell asyncTask that progressDialog has been dismissed. you can use one onDismissListener

```
    @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    if(id==DIALOG_PROGRESS_DIALOG){
        stockProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
        stockProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
        stockProgressDialog.setMessage("Check the post");
        stockProgressDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                textView.setText("Waiting the 5 secs...");
                myAsyncTask.execute("start it");
                //Or myAsyncTask.cancel(true); if you want to interrupt your asyncTask
            }
        });
        return stockProgressDialog;
    } else return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

Comment: I put onDismissListener on new thread for progressDialog. it's work. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel an AsyncTask by calling [AsyncTask.cancel(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) and then start up a new AsyncTask.  You are not supposed to run the AsyncTask as a parallel activity - it is supposed to be able to run and finish without outside intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Extend async and look into returning a result from doInBackground. onProgress update can dismiss your Progress dialog under control of the async task. Handle the result from doInBackground in onPostExecute.

```
//create the task
theBackground = new Background();
theBackground.execute("");
--------

private class Background extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        protected  String doInBackground(String...str ) {
            publishProgress("@@0");
                        //do a bunch of stuff
                        publishProgress(@001);
                        return("true");

              }
              protected void onProgressUpdate(String... str ) {
               //do stuff based on the progress string and eventually
               myProgressDialog.dismiss();
               }
               protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using a thread in one case, but an AsyncTask in another when you could just use two AsyncTasks... Actually, unless I'm missing something, in your case the most straightforward way is to combine the two bits of work into one AsyncTask and simply create and destroy the dialog in the AsyncTask callbacks. In pseudo-code:

```
onPreExecute
    show dialog
doInBackground
    do internet stuff
onPostExecute
    update views
    close dialog
```

Is there a reason why you're trying to update the views in its own AsyncTask? If you're updating views, you probably need to do the work in the UI thread anyway...

Comment: for the one thread I am using for the validation to internet. After the validation confirm, then I need to get all list from internet to display on listview by asynctask.